# How to return part of a string from a mysql table filed by select query?

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a `channel` filed in `mysql` table which contain following data:

```
DAHDI/69-1
DAHDI/68-1
DAHDI/20-1
DAHDI/1-1 
DAHDI/6-1 
DAHDI/67-1
DAHDI/14-1
DAHDI/4-1 
DAHDI/19-1
DAHDI/20-1
```

From the above data I want to fetch the numeric values after forward slash and before -1.

Expected result:

From `DAHDI/69-1` to `69` only.

Please note that `DAHDI` and `1` is fixed value in that `channel` filed.

**Edited:** I expect top most 100 rows which contains maximum numeric values from the million of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to locate your character indexes in the String, then do a simple calculation to extract the value. The query should be similar to this:

```
SELECT 0 + substring(channel, 
                     locate('/', channel) + 1, 
                     locate('-', channel) - locate('/', channel) - 1) AS myvalue
FROM table
ORDER BY myvalue DESC
LIMIT 100
```

`SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)`:
returns a substring len characters long from string str, starting at position pos.

`LOCATE(substr,str)`:
returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str.

The `0 +` trick forces MySql to convert the string to a number value.

Comment: This is working fine, can you please let me know how could I get the 100 rows those contain top most numeric values (i.e 479, 450, 430, ......200)?

Comment: I edited the answer, you should edit the question to reflect this new need, so the answer matches perfectly the question.